# Script that can automatically download new data from the server to my local backup

Tags: python, linux, shell, backup

I have an *application* running on ***linux* server** and I need to create a *local backup* of it's data.

However, *new data* is being added to the application after *every hour* and I want to *sync* my local backup data with server's data.

I want to write a script (*shell or python*) that can automatically *download* new added data from the ***linux* server** to my local machine backup. But I am newbie to the linux envoirnment and don't know how to write shell script to achieve this.

*What is the better way of achieving this ? And what would be the script to do so ?*

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0):

[rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) -r fits in your use case and it's a single line command.

```
rsync -r source destination
```

or the options you need according to your specific case.

So, you don't need a python script for that, but you can still write it and let it use the command above.
Moreover, if you want the Python script to do it in an automatic way, you may check the [event scheduler module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html).

Comment: Does it automatically sync files (once run; no need to run again) or Do we have to run each time to sync local and remote ?

Comment: Each time you want to sync files you run it, but you could schedule the sync every certain amount of time (e.g., every hour) scheduling it, or by using cron.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where and how your data is stored on the Linux server, but you could write a network application which pushes the data to a client and the client saves the data on the local machine. You can use sockets for that.

If the data is available via aan http server and you know how to write RESTful APIs, you could use that as well and make a task run on your local machine every hour which calls the REST API and handles its (JSON) data. Keep in mind that you need to secure the API if the server is running online and not in the same LAN.

You could also write a small application which downloads the files every hour from the server over FTP (if you want to backup files stored on the system). You will need to know the exact path of the file(s) to do this though.

All solutions above are meant for Python programming. Using a shell script is possible, but a little more complicated. I would use Python for this kind of tasks, as you have a lot of network related libraries available (ftp, socket, http clients, simple http servers, WSGI libraries, etc.)